# Using string instead of kind of shape in createShape()

Tags: java, processing

I want to pass an array of strings to a function in `draw()` and have the function draw each shape with the first parameter specifying which type of shape to draw. Here's my code (inside of `draw()`):

```
params = new String[]{"LINE","0","0","2","3"};
if (params.length == 2) {
  createShape(params[0],float(params[1]));
} else if (params.length == 3) {
  createShape(params[0],float(params[1]),float(params[2]));
} ...
} else if (params.length == 5) {
  createShape(params[0],float(params[1]),float(params[2]),float(params[3]),float(params[4]));
} ...
```

The ellipsis marks denote more else if statements with different numbers of parameters. I know that passing values to createShape() in this way seems redundant, but it's the best way I could find to serve my purpose, and I would like to know how to make it work. Currently, this code gives me an error and says `The function createShape() expects parameters like: "createShape(int,)"`.

Is there any way to get around this, or will I have to specify a case for every single kind of shape?

Comment: why not show us the `createShape` method?

Comment: The `createShape(kind,p)` function draws a `kind` (can be things like LINE, ELLIPSE, RECT) with parameters `p` where `p` is some array of floats. I'm pretty sure it's specific to the processing library . Here's the documentation: https://processing.org/reference/createShape_.html

Comment: Yes, as per the link you sent me *Parameters 
kind int: either POINT, LINE, TRIANGLE, QUAD, RECT, ELLIPSE, ARC, BOX, SPHERE*  The first parameter e.g. `LINE`  is actually an integer.  It will be defined somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this out of the box, but you could do something like this:

```
void createMyShape(String[] myArray){
  if(myArray[0].equals("LINE")){
    Shape s = createShape(LINE);
    s.vertex(int(myArray[1]), int(myArray[2]));
    s.vertex(int(myArray[3]), int(myArray[4]));
    s.endShape();
  }
  else if ...
}
```

This function parses the `myArray` parameter and uses `if` statements to take the right actions to create a shape. It also uses the `int()` function to parse the string array.

Note that this is not a great design. You should probably not use a String array for this. It's probably better to use a class to encapsulate your data.